# Making a div box an anchor - how to keep properties of the div box

Tags: html, css

I made a section with container and 4 boxes inside (flexbox with row direction). Everything was set up. Now I would like to make these 4 boxes clickable and set them as anchors. Unfortunately, when I packed my box into , it looses properties like width. should I changed my , or maybe it is a better way to make my boxes as anchors? Thanks for reply

```css
.icon-boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  margin: 0 -15px;

  :hover {
    background-color: #ffede9;
  }

  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;

    .box {
      width: calc(100% / 3);
      padding: 15px 15px;

      @media (max-width: 800px) {
        width: 100%;
      }

      .icon {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 60px;
      }

      .title {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        font-weight: 600;
      }

      .desc {
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 1.4;
        color: $secondaryColor;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
            <div class="icon-boxes">
                <a href="">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="icon"><img src="assets/img/wedding-invitation.png" alt=""></div>
                        <div class="title">Lorem</div>
                        <div class="desc">Lorem</div>
                    </div>
                </a>
             </div>
```

Comment: Please could you look at your question as we see it as bits are missing - for example: 'when I packed my box into ' what does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using some javascript. It would keep all the div properties and you won't need an anchor.

> 

```js
var d1 = document.getElementById("d1")
d1.addEventListener("click",function(){
   window.open("https://www.google.com" ,'_blank');
})
```

```css
.d1{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:crimson;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1" id="d1"> </div>
```